# iOS Simulator not giving me sandbox option for Game Center

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios-simulator, game-center

I'm making an iPhone SpriteKit-based game, and I just added all the code for game center, but when I try to run it I get a pop-up window that says, "Game Center unavailable, player is not signed in". So I was looking through the game center programming guide and it says that I am supposed to enable the sandbox option, but when I go into Settings then Game Center, there is no option to enable the sandbox. I only get an option for logging. I was wondering how I can enable sandbox in Game Center so I can hopefully solve this issue.

Comment: check out this link for the steps you may have missed when incorporating game center. have you plugged in the authenticate player code? anyway here is the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1

Comment: I completed all the steps and plugged in the authenticate player code

Comment: Forgot to add authenticate player to my didMoveToView it works perfectly now thanks. Still have the sandbox issue though.

Comment: I'm not sure if sand boxing is a requirement under iOS 8 and later anymore. If I'm not wrong Xcode takes care of that part.

Comment: i misread your question. well part of it only. i already answered part of it,but sandboxing option is not available on simulator. it is available when you load your game on device.

Comment: It's possible to get these types of errors if the bundle identifier in your Xcode info.plist doesn't match the one in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you viewed this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html)?

You may need to sign **out** of your GameCenter account before you can do this.

Comment: Yes that is the link I was using. Under Developer it doesn't give me a Sandbox option. I also tried signing out.

Answer (score 0):

When I signed into Gamecenter, signed out, signed back in then switched to myapp I see "Welcome back ***sandbox***". It looks like Sandbox is automatic in the simulator.